# What are the potential problems of .Net on Linux

Tags: windows, linux, .net-4.0

What are the potential problems(if any) deploying/installing a Windows application(WPF/WinForms) which uses .Net4 onto a Linux server?

I'd love to hear from any that have experience doing something similar.

Thanks

Comment: One potential problem is that many of the various .NET libraries (assemblies) that Microsoft publishes on the Windows platform are not available for Linux

Comment: Are you asking specifically about Mono, or are you unaware that Microsoft's .NET Framework offerings won't run on Linux? (More importantly, why are you deploying a *desktop* application in WinForms or WPF on a *server* ?)

Comment: No not Mono. The application will be developed on a Windows machine.

Comment: So, the latter. You can't run Microsoft's CLR on Linux. Mono is *also* a .NET runtime implementation. It looks like David's answer below covers the rest of the details, but the short version is what you're asking is impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common .NET runtime implementation on Linux is [Mono](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mono-project.com%2F&ei=kKFGTYn-BMSohAe9xKSCAg&usg=AFQjCNHVts-EqhUHaT4QJLm5yVTUXvWnUA&sig2=xRg14KH9F_bdeEJOh_UNAw). However, this does not support WPF, nor does it yet fully support the .NET 4 framework class library. Microsoft's own CLR won't run on anything but Windows, so unless and until you can find an alternative runtime that supports .NET 4 and WPF, you won't be able to do this.

Comment: So is it possible then to have a WinForms app in .Net35 and have full functionality of the framework?

Comment: @Chris: No, you won't get full functionality. Not everything available in Microsoft's implementation has been ported to Mono. But most things have. You can see more [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility).